# Can't stream Airplay after upgrading to iOS 7

Tags: ios, airplay

I have an Iphone 4 and a Mac Mini running 10.6.8 and Airserver. With iOS 6, I used to be able to stream video from my Iphone to the Mac using Airplay; however, after upgrading to iOS 7, I can't do that anymore:

- If I start a video, hit the Airplay button in the video player and choose the Mac,
  it will tell me "The operation could not be completed".
- If I choose the Airplay button in the Control Center and then hit
  Play, it will ignore me and reset the choice in the Airplay menu to
  my iPhone.
- The only thing I can "stream" are photos: if I activate Airplay in the Control Center and then access my Photos app, the pictures will appear in the Mac.

This happens both with my Mac Mini and with a Macbook running 10.8.5.

Can anyone confirm whether this is a bug, or they dropped support for Airplay with my Iphone in iOS 7?

Comment: Well, they didn't drop support…

Comment: The way I see it, if I used to be able to do something with a piece of hardware and I can't anymore, then it's the manufacturer who has "dropped support". Or remove a feature that used to work. Anyway, I just wanted to confirm that it isn't a bug on my part, but an intentional behaviour by Apple.